# Инвертирование номера через for

Tags: c

```
printf("Introduza o numero: ");
scanf("%i", &numero);

for (i = 1; numero >= i; i++) {
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (g = i - 1; g > 0; g--) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (i = 1; numero > i; i++) {
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (g = i - 1; g > 0; g--) {
        printf("%i", g);
    }
    for (k = i; k < numero; k++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Есть вот этот код, выдает вот такое

[image]

Нужно снизу вверх инвертировать, подскажите как, решать не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил Ваш код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, k, g, numero;

    printf("Introduza o numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);

    for (i = 1; numero >= i; i++) 
    {
        for (k = i; k < numero; k++) 
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) 
        {
            printf("%i", g);
        }

        for (g = i - 1; g > 0; g--) 
        {
            printf("%i", g);
        }

        for (k = i; k < numero; k++) 
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = numero; i>=1; i--)  
    {
        for (k = i; k < numero; k++) 
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        if (i < numero)
        {
              for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) 
              {
                  printf("%i", g);
              }

              for (g = i - 1; g > 0; g--) 
              {
                  printf("%i", g);
              }
        }

        for (k = i; k < numero; k++) 
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        if (i < numero)
           printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\nDavi na knopku ANY KEY!!!");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно, что это условие не самый удачный вариант решения, но это то, что первое приходит в голову:

```
if (i < numero)
        {
              for (g = 1; g <= i; g++) 
              {
                  printf("%i", g);
              }

              for (g = i - 1; g > 0; g--) 
              {
                  printf("%i", g);
              }
        }
```